# How can I make my flex-item be on it's own line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am a new user to flexbox and just read a quick guide to get started on the topic, so what am trying to do is a vertical flex, which I've achieved with the h3 and p aligned with the image however I would like the paragraph tag to be on it's own line and not on the same line as the h3. I tried doing a 
 as well as changing its display.

```html
    <div class="recent-conversations">
        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">
            <h3>Mohammed</h3>
            <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">
            <h3>Mohammed</h3>
            <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">
            <h3>Mohammed</h3>
            <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
/* Recent Conversations */
.recent-conversations {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* Flexbox item */
.conversation {
    display: inline-flex;
}

/* Profile Picture */
.conversation img {
    width: 5%;
}

/* Display name */
.conversation h3 {
}

/* Recent message */
.conversation p {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `flex-wrap: wrap` rule for `.conversation` class. This allows items to move to different lines.

For tag `p`, set the `flex: 0 0 100%`. This will move this element to a new line.

**This is just advice:** Also, you can use `display: inherit` for class `.conversation`. Because the parent `.recent-conversations` of this class is **flex**. Therefore, you can **inherit** it.

```css
.recent-conversations {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.conversation {
    display: inherit;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.conversation img {
    width: 5%;
}

.conversation h3 {
}

.conversation p {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="recent-conversations">
    <div class="conversation">
        <img src="img/avatar.png" />
        <h3>Mohammed</h3>
        <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="conversation">
        <img src="img/avatar.png" />
        <h3>Mohammed</h3>
        <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="conversation">
        <img src="img/avatar.png" />
        <h3>Mohammed</h3>
        <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you think having a unordered list and then list items would be a better use case for this or should I use flex?

Comment: @Abow, For your template, I would choose flex.

Comment: @Abow, No problem. I was reading your new question just at that time. Coincidence :)

Answer (score 0):

Group your headers and paragraphs inside a div like so:

```html
<div class="conversation">
    <img src="img/avatar.png">
    <div>
        <h3>Mohammed</h3>
        <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you think having a unordered list and then list items would be a better use case for this or should I use flex?

Comment: This solution seems just fine